# Silverstripe: Cleaning up URLs

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I currently have a module which displays a staff profile. It works like so:

- Staff Holder: Displays a list of all staff members
- Staff Profile: Displays a database record from "StaffMember" table.

Staff Profile uses the template "StaffHolder_profile.ss". Obviously, 'profile' is the action that displays the staff profile. The display profile action works on a URL that looks like this:

'http://***domain***/staff/profile/***id of record***'

I've been asked to remove the "profile/id" from these URLs. As far as I'm aware, this is not possible, as the module depends on the URL in order to work? (It uses URL Variables...)

Is this true? Is there a way I can essentially "clean up" the URL so that the new URL will be "http://domain/staff/staff-member-name"

Comment: You could achieve this with a custom route, but presumably member name's aren't unique so you'll run into issues with members with the same name.

Comment: Do you handle this as front-end page or in CMS? Do you have login system for users? (then current user can be found in session, see CMS Member class) Do you use SiteTree::nested_urls? (then StaffProfile can be nested page.) and Yes, you can handle your clean url in `StaffHolder_Controller::index($request)` where `$name = $request->getParam('ID');`

Comment: @GregSmirnov Thanks for the reply. This is front-end. Yes there's a log in system, however the staff page is to display a list of dataobjects as pages. It's not a current user's profile. What is a nested url? What does that Controller function do exactly?

Comment: @Dallby to get around first name + lastname conflicts between staff members with the same name you could append the ID to the URL as well, e.g. `domain/staff/123-staff-member-name`

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve that specific url pattern by overriding the routing param 'Action' in your page controller's index. I wouldn't suggest this. Instead, I would recommend that you create a specific Action for the page e.g 'domain/staff/view/...'. My below examples do override the routing param 'Action', but only to fulfill your question.

You can base your identifiers on a name, but inconsistencies like missing details and/or matching names create issues - much of which are not covered by these examples. A unique identifier would be far better.

I haven't test run any of this code, so sorry for errors.

-

**Example 1:** Slower, but less work required.

StaffHolder_Controller:

```
public function index() {

    /**
     * @internal This will display the first match ONLY. If you'd like to
     * account for member's with exactly the same name, generate and store the
     * slug against their profile... See Example 2 for that.
     */

    // Re-purpose the 'Action' URL param (not advisable)
    $slug = $this->getRequest()->param('Action');

    // Partial match members by first name
    $names = explode('-', $slug);
    $matches = Member::get()->filter('FirstName:PartialMatch', $names[0]);

    // Match dynamically
    $member = null;
    foreach($matches as $testMember) {
        // Uses preg_replace to remove all non-alpha characters
        $testSlug = strtolower(
            sprintf(
                '%s-%s',
                preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/", '', $testMember->FirstName),
                preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/", '', $testMember->Surname)
            )
        ); // Or use Member::genereateSlug() from forthcoming example MemberExtension

        // Match member (will stop at first match)
        if($testSlug == $slug) {
            $member = $testMember;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Handle invalid requests
    if(!$member) {
        return $this->httpError(404, 'Not Found');
    }

    /**
     * @internal If you're lazy and want to use your existing template
     */
    return $this->customise(array(
        'Profile' => $member
        ))->renderWith(array('StaffHolder_profile', 'Page'));

}
```

-

**Example 2:**

config.yml:

```
Member:
  extensions:
    - MemberExtension
```

MemberExtension.php:

```
class MemberExtension extends DataExtension {

    private static $db = array(
        'Slug' => 'Varchar' // Use 'Text' if it's likely that there will be a value longer than 255
    );

    public function generateSlug() {
        // Uses preg_replace to remove all non-alpha characters
        return strtolower(
            sprintf(
                '%s-%s',
                preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/", '', $this->owner->FirstName),
                preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/", '', $this->owner->Surname)
            )
        );
    }

    public function onBeforeWrite() {

        // Define slug
        if(!$this->owner->Slug)) {
            $slug = $this->generateSlug();

            $count = Member::get()->filter('Slug:PartialMatch', $slug)->Count();

            // Check for unique
            $unique = null;
            $fullSlug = $slug;
            while(!$unique) {
                // Add count e.g firstname-surname-2
                if($count > 0) {
                    $fullSlug = sprintf('%s-%s', $slug, ($count+1));
                }

                // Check for pre-existing
                if(Member::get()->filter('Slug:PartialMatch', $fullSlug)->First()) {
                    $count++; // (Try again with) increment
                } else {
                    $unique = true;
                }
            }

            // Update member
            $this->owner->Slug = $fullSlug;
        }

    }

}
```

StaffHolder_Controller:

```
public function index() {

    // Re-purpose the action URL param (not advisable)
    $slug = $this->getRequest()->param('Action');

    // Check for member
    $member = Member::get()->filter('Slug', $slug)->first();

    // Handle invalid requests
    if(!$member) {
        return $this->httpError(404, 'Not Found');
    }

    /**
     * @internal If you're lazy and want to use your existing template
     */
    return $this->customise(array(
        'StaffMember' => $member
        ))->renderWith('StaffHolder_profile');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested urls is default behaviour of SiteTree class. Every child page URL segment is added to the parent full URL. So with the following page hierarchy you get clean urls

```
Staff (StaffHolder, /staff)
|- John Doe (StaffProfilePage, /staff/john-doe)
|- Marie Smith (StaffProfilePage, /staff/marie-smith)
```

You can get a list of staff profile pages in the StaffHolder.ss template with

```
<ul>
<% loop $Children %>
    <li><a href="$Link">$Title</a></li>
<% end_loop %>
</ul>
```